# R Markdown to PDF causes lines to overflow off page

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I'm having an issue with R notebook where when I converted it to PDF, the lines overflow but this doesn't happen in the html view of it.

This is what it looks like when I press preview and the code doesn't overflow,
[image: HTML]

However this is what the PDF looks like where the Mall_Customers line overflows off the page. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Sometimes a quick work around is rendering the document to HTML, like the "preview" version of the notebook, and then **print** to PDF from the web browser

Comment: Long lines of code may not get wrapped especially if there is a quoted element. Just wrap the lines manually in the code block. Or break the line into two with `path <- "~Desktop . . . .csv` followed by `Mall_Customers <- read.csv(path)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the appearance of codes in your PDF files via LaTeX's [fvextra](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package. You can call it and configure the settings of it via `header-includes` in the YAML header of your Rmd file:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - |
    ```{=latex}
    \usepackage{fvextra}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{
      showspaces = false,
      showtabs = false,
      breaklines,
      commandchars=\\\{\}
    }
    ```
---
````