# In R markdown in RStudio, how can I prevent the source code from running off a pdf page when bash language is used?

Tags: bash, r-markdown, rstudio, bookdown

I'm writing a technical book using Bookdown and RStudio. My code chunks are mainly using `bash`. Everything works fine except when I export the book to pdf, then the source code is partially out of the "box" and even the page if this is long enough. I have read a lot of solutions when `r` language is used, but none of these solutions works when `bash` language is used.

Here is my code at the beginning of the `.Rmd` file:

````
```{r, global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE, eval=FALSE, 
tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60), tidy=TRUE)
```
````

And then when I write the code chunk:

````
```{bash}
mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://cluster0.rh6qzzz.mongodb.net/" --db sample_mflix --username my_username
```
````

The outputs were produced as shown below (see the end of line):
[image: example_1]
[image: example_2]

I would like to avoid this, but I have not found the solution.

Comment: I think the same thing happens when you use any code. At least it happens when I try to display markdown code source.

Comment: @biorubenfs Have you tried [a solution using LaTeX's fvextra package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69387188/10215301)?